# Android like permissions in iOS

Tags: ios, permissions, manifest, ios-permissions

In android, you define permissions for gps, sms sending, location , .., in the manifest file.
Is there anything similar in the iOS, so the user would know what capabilities of the phone some app uses before installation?
Or is the user warned during app use when some function wants to use something (e.g. gps, sms...)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In iOS you declare your application requirements in its manifest-like `Info.plist`. But this information is not used to ask user permission, only for ensuring device compatibility.

Only Notifications and Location Services require user permission, which is **automatically** asked to the user the very first time your application attempt to use the corresponding API.

My guess is that many other permissions are already granted via the Apple Store license agreement, that the user must have accepted, unlike Android *(I guess you can install an app without using the market isnt? which changes a lot from a legal point of view)*

Answer (score 4):

There's no such things as permissions on iPhone.

The only thing that user is warned about is when application uses his current location - then user is prompted with system alert and must explicitly allow or deny application's access to location data.

What concerns sms and email, they can be created and sent only via standard controllers so user will be aware of that anyway

Answer (score 0):

on iOS you don't have to declare all necessary permissions in some specific file. You just use them. For example location

info.plist

```
//Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>title</string>
//Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>description</string>
```

```
import CoreLocation

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

}
```

[[IDFA]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63994871/4770877)