# What is the equivalent of Android permissions in iOS development?

Tags: android, ios, security, permissions, ios-permissions

I am not sure how to search for this so even a bunch of keywords would be enough or +1 if someone can point me to the relevant documentation.

Android has approx. 122 permissions described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html). What is the equivalent in iOS? Do developers declare permissions or can they access everything? If everything, where can I find what this "everything" entails?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5822910/1321873

Answer (score 4):

Although there are key differences in the way `iOS` and `Android` access the system, what Apple have done is to let you use some system resources (such as contacts or photos for example) and also register your app via some keys in a property list for using features such as background execution (for example a voip application that would like to listen for incoming calls). [You can find all these options (keys) here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW2)

Answer (score 3):

There is no manifest-like permission concept in iOS. You can access every public API, as long as it is not against the developer agreement, and if you do something wrong, your application will be rejected by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of "permissions" in iOS, there are certain things you are allowed to do and certain things you are not. You need not ask the user for access to these permissions.

I don't know of a specific list of things you are allowed to do, but the [Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) should give you a good idea.

Comment: Thank You. The link you posted requires a username/password. Can I register as an Apple Developer and access it or do I need to pay?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in iOS unfortunately. You might interested in reading this [article](http://palpapers.plynt.com/issues/2011Oct/android-vs-ios/) about the difference between iOS and Android on this particular point.

Comment: That's pretty much the case, but not entirely true. For example an application will ask for user's permission before tracking his location (though I do not know if that is the case in all iOS versions... hmm).

Comment: @Alladinian That's true. The user can actually go in the settings and disable certain permissions per app.

Comment: @AmokraneChentir link is dead :( can you please help

Comment: @rakeshkashyap The link is not relevant anymore. I recommend just reading the official documentation https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/app-architecture/requesting-permission/

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of permissions for iOS (iOS 5; may happen in iOS 6 but do not count on it).  You can only access official API as approved by Apple. Use of any unofficial API is not permitted and as such will in most cases leads to your app being rejected for distribution in the AppStore.

The closest you will find to permissions in notifications you see when using Location. See more @: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH18-SW10

Regards,
Bo