# How to get UDID of iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want unique device ID for iPhone that remains unchanged?, I want Unique device ID that cannot be changed if I uninstall application and install again on same device.
I am Using swift 2.1.1 and xcode 7.2.1.
I have tried this code but both will not work.

**//First approach**

> let device_id =
>   UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
>   print("unique device id: (device_id)")

**//Second approach**

> let dID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault)
>  let deviceID =
>   CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, dID) as NSString
>   print("unique CFUUID id: (deviceID)")

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944504/how-to-retrieve-iphone-idfa-from-api/29832833#29832833 ?

Comment: have you solved it ?

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3.X** Latest simple usage;

```
if let identifierForVendor = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor {
    print(identifierForVendor.uuidString)
}
```

Comment: this will reset though when app is deleted...

Comment: This is different for every app and also, it changes every time we delete and reinstall the app

Comment: This is not udid...this gives uuid

Comment: We need UDID. It provide UUID

Answer (score 6):

Try this ,

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor
```

or if you want a string:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
print(UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor().UUIDString()) //Print Log
```

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 6):

This is working in swift 3 / Xcode / Iphone7 for me.

```
let deviceUUID: String = (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!
```

Comment: thank you for the swift 3 implementation - really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
let UUID = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, CFUUIDCreate(nil))
 func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if userDefaults.objectForKey("ApplicationUniqueIdentifier") == nil {
    let UUID = NSUUID.UUID().UUIDString
    userDefaults.setObject(UUID, forKey: "ApplicationUniqueIdentifier")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
return true
```

}

This will work correctly in swift

Answer (score 1):

```
print( UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor().UUIDString())
```

Comment: It is working for u or not?? Let me know ???

Comment: it is UUID not UDID