# Checking iOS app permissions. Publish an app

Tags: ios

I just finished my first app, and uses the camera to scan a QR code, check the wifi to which you are connected, it prints a list, and uses the facebook account if the user wants to post something.

I do not know if I have to say this when I upload the app to the apple store, or notify it to the user when the application is being  installed on the device.

I found this response  from 2011 saying no, but I'm not sure if there has been changes since then:
[Android like permissions in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822830/android-like-permissions-in-ios)

Thanks.

Comment: When your app tries to do something that requires permission, the system will prompt the user to OK or Don't Allow. You don't need to notify the user yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that were like Android permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, you don't have any need to tale any kind of permission. You can upload your application to iTunes without any permission..(Y)